# Отправка email-уведомлений с записью в cache-файл. PHP

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть функция отправки email-уведомлений на почту администратора. Функция рабочая (уведомление приходит), но она срабатывает каждый раз когда обновляешь страницу.

Есть ли способы хранить информацию об отправленном сообщении к кэш-файле и каждый раз при перезагрузке браузера не отправлялось?

```
            $date_to_check = new DateTime($arElementItem['PROP']['PRIK']['VALUE']);
            $now = new DateTime(); // время сейчас   
                if ( $now->getTimestamp() == $date_to_check->getTimestamp()) {
            $to = $arElementItem['PROP']['EMAIL']['VALUE']; 
            $subject = 'Дата принятия комерческой части';
            $message = 'Дата принятия комерческой части просрочена';
               mail($to, $subject, $message); 
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция есть такая конечно

```
$cache = Bitrix\Main\Data\Cache::createInstance(); 
if ($cache->initCache($cacheTime, $cacheId, $cacheDir)) { 
    $result = $cache->getVars(); 
} elseif ($cache->startDataCache()) { 
    // Здесь выполняем нужные действия
    $cache->endDataCache($result); 
}
```

Только в данном случае потребность в ней говорит об ошибках в архитектуре вашего проекта.

1. Раз она срабатывает каждый раз значит вы этот код не туда
   вставляете или не обрабатываете эту возможность (обновление
   страницы) при приеме какой то формы. Если принимаете формы, делайте
   в конце редирект.  А может вообще будет правильнее обработать
   соответствующие событие АПИ
2. грамотнее было бы использовать не mail
   а
   [СEvent::SendImmediate](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cevent/sendimmediate.php)  или СEvent::Send
   и сделать специальное событие и шаблон.

Comment: Пробывал через СEvent::Send, но как то не пошло, с моими знаниями PHP и bitrix пока не понятно как эта конструкция работает.

Comment: Для него необходимо создать почтовое событие и шаблон письма для этого события. SendImmediate отправляет сразу, Send - ставит в очередь. Тут уже зависит от того как у вас запускаются агенты.
Но если бы вы  данный код вставили эти методы, все равно у вас дважды будет приходить. Т.к. проблема у вас за пределами указанного кода. И тут уже увы вам либо изучать бесплатные курсы Битрикс (https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/) до "Разработчик Bitrix Framwork"... Либо привлекать специалистов пока не поздно.  Проект в итоге наберет критическую массу и его будет легче сделать с 0 или вообще закрыть.

Comment: Я дорабатываю проект уже готовый дело в этом... у меня нет выбора)) сделай любой ценой называется...

Comment: На проектах с таким подходом как у вас любят отключать кеширование. Учтите, что в этом случае код который "Здесь выполняем нужные действия" так же будет выполняться всегда

Comment: Учту, спасибо вам